# Symfony 2.8 Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class ... could not be converted to string (one to many and many to one)

Tags: php, symfony, orm, crud, foreign-key-relationship

This is my first question here, so please forgive me if I omitted something.

I have 2 entities defined: Product and Category.

```
<?php

namespace Backend\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Backend\AdminBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="parent_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $parentId;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param integer $status
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set parentId
     *
     * @param integer $parentId
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setParentId($parentId)
    {
        $this->parentId = $parentId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parentId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getParentId()
    {
        return $this->parentId;
    }
}
```

and

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Backend\AdminBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="short_description", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $shortDescription;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="full_description", type="text")
     */
    private $fullDescription;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float")
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $categoryId;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set shortDescription
     *
     * @param string $shortDescription
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setShortDescription($shortDescription)
    {
        $this->shortDescription = $shortDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shortDescription
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getShortDescription()
    {
        return $this->shortDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Set fullDescription
     *
     * @param string $fullDescription
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setFullDescription($fullDescription)
    {
        $this->fullDescription = $fullDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fullDescription
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFullDescription()
    {
        return $this->fullDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param float $price
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return float 
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param integer $status
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set categoryId
     *
     * @param integer $categoryId
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setCategoryId($categoryId)
    {
        $this->categoryId = $categoryId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get categoryId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getCategoryId()
    {
        return $this->categoryId;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param \Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\Category $category
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setCategory(\Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\Category 
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
}
```

I've managed to properly set the relation between them as Category has Many Product and Product has one Category.

I successfully created my CRUD for Category and it works.

I was able to create my CRUD for Product, accessed the index route and works just fine.

The issue is that when I try to create a new Product I get the following exception:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Backend\AdminBundle\Entity\Category could not be converted to string

It's my first Symfony test project and beside being a total noob, I'm stuck. I know I must be omitting something extremely obvious but I just can't tell what.

I'm using Symfony 2.8.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a magic method __toString() for your `Category` entity.

For sample, do it like this:

```
public function __toString() 
{
    return $this->getName();
}
```